# WiX toolset: How run an installer in a bundle based on choices made in an earlier installer in the same bundle?

Tags: installation, wix

What I'm trying to implement is a way to only install specific 3rd party dependencies in the bundle if the user chooses to install software components that require those 3rd party dependencies.

Our more specific use case:
In the bundle, we first run a custom installer for our own software where the user chooses the features they need. The user might choose to install a piece of software that uses laser scanners to detect things. If the user does choose that option, then a 3rd party laser scanner configurator software should be installed later in the bundle.

What I have tried so far is adding the following `util:FileSearch` element in the `Bundle` element:

```
<util:FileSearch Id="CheckOurSoftwareExists"
                 Path="[WindowsVolume]\Company\Software\OurSoftware\OurSoftware.exe"
                 Variable="OURSOFTWAREEXISTS"
                 Result="exists" />
```

and using that in an `ExePackage` element inside `Chain` element:

```
<ExePackage Id="LaserScannerConfiguratorInstaller"
            SourceFile="3rd-party-installers\path\to\laser-scanner-configurator-installer.exe"
            InstallCondition="OURSOFTWAREEXISTS" />
```

This doesn't work because `util:FileSearch` is supposedly executed already before any of the bundled installers are started. Even though if `InstallCondition` attribute is evaluated right before the 3rd party installer is started, the variable `OURSOFTWAREEXISTS` has already been given a value earlier.

So what kind of workarounds are there for this issue?

Comment: Is the feature selection occurring in the bootstrapper ui or the msi ui?

Comment: @ChristopherPainter The feature selection is currently happening in the MSI UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still using MSI Native UI is the core of your problem.  The WiX dev team does not recommend this.

If you disable your native MSI UI and have the user make the choice in the bootstrapper UI you can then use that as a condition to install your EXE package or not and pass the property to your MSI to control what features get installed.

Otherwise I suspect you'd have to write a custom bootstrapper application that reevaluates the properties after the MSI has been installed and recosts which packages are to be installed.

I suppose a quick ugly hack would be to write a custom EXE wrapper for the EXE that reads the machine to see if the feature was installed and either chooses to call the real EXE or exits without installing it.